# Adding MapBox WMTS to MapInfo Pro Zoom Error

Tags: mapbox, mapinfo, wmts

Not sure what's causing this problem, but I cannot see the tiles being loaded on my MapInfo. I know that the API call to the server is working, but it cannot fetch tiles because of the zoom level?

I'm using MapInfo V16.0 (64 bit). It's an old version and probably no longer supported by Precisely since Pitney Bowes was bought. So I don't think I can access their Knowledge Community for help. Kind of desperate.

The styled map is set to public and the options menu for web services in MapInfo is not using a proxy server. It is set to my system settings.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there was an issue with the Mapbox WMTS in MapInfo Pro v16.

This problem was fixed in MapInfo Pro v17.0.3 in case someone else runs into a similar problem with an older version of MapInfo Pro.